# Passing parameters in the arcgis toolbox

Tags: python, python-2.x, arcgis, arcpy

I'm trying to put some functioning code into a python toolbox in arcgis (Python 2.7).
I've run the code externally using arcpy.
I've setup a new python toolbox, edited a single parameter, a string with a site code e.g. SiteX.
This should set the default online_id to "SiteX" and the SiteCode to "SiteX20".

The messages list all the feature classes but it is not liking `arcpy.AssignDefaultToField_management()`:

```
class Tool(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the tool (tool name is the name of the class)."""
        self.label = "Tool"
        self.description = ""
        self.canRunInBackground = False

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        """Define parameter definitions"""

        param0 = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Site Code",
            name="online_id",
            # datatype="Field",
            datatype="GPString",
            # parameterType="Optional",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input")

        params = [param0]
        # params = None
        return params

    def isLicensed(self):
        """Set whether tool is licensed to execute."""
        return True

    def updateParameters(self, parameters):
        """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
        validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
        has been changed."""
        return

    def updateMessages(self, parameters):
        """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
        parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
        return

    def execute(self, parameters, messages):


        online_id = parameters  # user request required
        # online_id = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(online_id)
        # online_id = raw_input('Enter your value :')
        dateyr = time.strftime("%y", time.localtime())
        sitecode = str(online_id) + str(dateyr)

        arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.env.workspace + "\\survey"

        fclist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
        arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.env.workspace)
        arcpy.AddMessage(online_id)
        arcpy.AddMessage(sitecode)

        # Loop through all the feature classes and assign the default value for online_id
        for fc in fclist:
            arcpy.AddMessage(fc)
            arcpy.AddMessage("{0} has {1} features.".format(fc, online_id))
            arcpy.AssignDefaultToField_management(in_table=fc, field_name="online_id", default_value=online_id)
            # arcpy.AssignDefaultToField_management(in_table=fc, field_name="site_code", default_value=sitecode)

        return
```

Edit

The error message given by arcgis:

```
Executing: Tool X
Start Time: Tue Oct 06 15:57:33 2020
Running script Tool...
S:\PROJECTS\Workflow\GN_Coding\OA\03 GIS Projects - Coding Review\Geodatabase\DRS_survey_data.gdb\survey
[<geoprocessing parameter object object at 0x50DF5FC0>]
[<geoprocessing parameter object object at 0x50DF5FC0>]20
drafting_ply
drafting_ply has [<geoprocessing parameter object object at 0x50DF5FC0>] features.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 75, in execute
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.5\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 3574, in AssignDefaultToField
    raise e
RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool

Failed to execute (Tool).
Failed at Tue Oct 06 15:57:40 2020 (Elapsed Time: 7.53 seconds)
```

Comment: `but it is not liking arcpy.AssignDefaultToField_management()` - I'd assume people would need to know what it's not "liking" about it, like is it raising an exception or just not working as you'd expect it to?

Comment: I've added the error message if it helps any.

Comment: After an evening of further reading, I think I need to use `parameters[0].valueAsText` to get the first (only) parameter in the list object. Will try it when I'm back at work tomorrow.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, the exception arcgis raises seems a bit crap tbh. Apologies if you already know this, but for future reference, if you get an error like this, take it down to the most basic code possible (in this case, empty the `execute` method), and slowly re-introduce everything until the error occurs. If you then print out all the variables around that error, then you'll likely spot something that's different to what you were expecting.

Comment: I've been using ArcGIS for 15 odd years, so I'm used to ESRI's approach to 'coding'. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `online_id = parameters[0].value`.  This should give you online_id set to a string since your parameter is a string type.